# How do I un-ignore Captain Obvious?

Tags: support, chatbot

I have ignored "Captain Obvious". How do I get him back?

I have tried [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146616/how-can-i-un-ignore-a-user-in-chat), but It didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your chat-profile, there is a tab "prefs", where you can manage the users you are ignoring, there you can unignore users:

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

Ask a user to send you [Captain Obvious's profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-263/captain-obvious) link in [2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

[image: Ask]

And Click **don't ignore this user.**

[image: Captain]